# How to find a string, delete corresponding node and append two nodes using xmlstarlet

Tags: linux, shell, xmlstarlet

I have a file called FILE.XML

It looks like this

```
      <File>${IB}/OP/views/ACCOUNT.xml</File>
      <File>${IB}/OP/views/EMPLOYEES.xml</File
      <File>${IB}/OP/views/STATUS.xml</File>
```

I need to use `xmlstarlet` to look at FILE.XML and determine if there's a match for ACCOUNT.xml. If there is, append two additional lines beneath it. Including the tags and the full path as seen below.

```
<File>${IB}/OP/views/ACCOUNT_MAIN.xml</File>
<File>${IB}/OP/views/ACCOUNT_SECONDARY.xml</File>
```

Then delete ACCOUNT.xml line

```
<File>${IB}/OP/views/ACCOUNT.xml</File>
```

So I came up with a way to delete the line but not sure how to append the new ones before or after I delete.

Here's my delete command.

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -d '//rules/File[contains(text(),"{IB}/OP/view/ACCOUNT.xml")]' ${HOME}/file.xml
```

The final result in FILE.xml should look like this

```
      <File>${IB}/OP/views/ACCOUNT_MAIN.xml</File>
      <File>${IB}/OP/views/ACCOUNT_SECONDARY.xml</File>
      <File>${IB}/OP/views/EMPLOYEES.xml</File
      <File>${IB}/OP/views/STATUS.xml</File>
```

Answer (score 2):

Given this input,

```xml
<rules>
  <File>${IB}/OP/views/ACCOUNT.xml</File>
  <File>${IB}/OP/views/EMPLOYEES.xml</File>
  <File>${IB}/OP/views/STATUS.xml</File>
</rules>
```

this should do what you're after:

```sh
# shellcheck shell=sh disable=SC2016
xmlstarlet edit \
  --var T '//rules/File[contains(text(),"${IB}/OP/views/ACCOUNT.xml")]' \
  -a '$T' -t elem -n 'File' -v '${IB}/OP/views/ACCOUNT_SECONDARY.xml' \
  -a '$T' -t elem -n 'File' -v '${IB}/OP/views/ACCOUNT_MAIN.xml' \
  -d '$T' \
file.xml
```

`--var` defines a named variable, see examples in
[`xmlstarlet.txt`](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet.txt). If the `T` variable
matches nothing then input is not modified.

Answer (score 1):

##### Input

```
<root>
  <File>${IB}/OP/views/ACCOUNT_MAIN.xml</File>
  <File>${IB}/OP/views/ACCOUNT_SECONDARY.xml</File>
  <File>${IB}/OP/views/EMPLOYEES.xml</File
  <File>${IB}/OP/views/STATUS.xml</File>
</root>
```

##### What I would do:

```
xmlstarlet ed -L \
  -a '//File[contains(., "ACCOUNT.xml")]' -t elem -n File \
  -v '${IB}/OP/views/ACCOUNT_SECONDARY.xml' \
  -a '//File[contains(., "ACCOUNT.xml")]' -t elem -n File \
  -v '${IB}/OP/views/ACCOUNT_MAIN.xml' \
  -d '//File[contains(., "ACCOUNT.xml")]' file.xml
```

##### Output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <File>${IB}/OP/views/ACCOUNT_MAIN.xml</File>
  <File>${IB}/OP/views/ACCOUNT_SECONDARY.xml</File>
  <File>${IB}/OP/views/EMPLOYEES.xml</File>
  <File>${IB}/OP/views/STATUS.xml</File>
</root>
```